# Windows workflow suspends intermittently with error in DurableInstancing.InstancesTable

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I am facing this error since some time, it is very intermittent in nature so, unable to understand why this error and what needs t be done t fix this.

Issue:

We have a workflow 4.5 WCF service. Everything goes well, but intermittently we see suddenly that a workflow instance gets suspended with an error in the table "DurableInstancing.InstancesTable"

The error is "Keyword Not supported: 'DB Name,1433';Initial Catalog'.

Since most times this ust workd fine without any error, I do not think this problem is related to web.config entry for connectionstring. Most times the workflow completes without any error. We have verified multiple times that the connection string is proper and there is no issue with parsing the connection string.

I suspect this issue is happening while Workflow instance is being recreated from persistence storage, and because some reason it is unable to recreate , the workflow is getting suspended with this error in DB.

I really appreciate any help in getting us through this error.

Thanks,

GD

Answer (score 0):

What we found was it was an issue with permission in Database. We gave "dbo" user permission to the workflow database, and after that we have not seen this problem occur again. Has the error or exception that gets logged in the table is mre informative then it would have been better.

Thanks,

GD